# How to force Spring boot OAuth2 autoconfig to use another yml file instead of application.yml file?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I developed a spring boot application which is using OAuth2 autoconfigure but I am not able to force it to read client configurations from a yml file other than application.yml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to use multiple profiles and one client file by profile:

The first properties files named **application-my-client-1.yml** :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-client-1:
            client-id: ${APP-CLIENT-ID}
            client-secret: ${APP-CLIENT-SECRET}
            client-name: my-client user
            provider: my-client
            scope: user
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/my-client
```

Activated by setting the my-client-1 profile to on when running the spring boot app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=my-client-1 myApplication.jar
```

The second properties files named **application-my-client-2.yml** :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-client-2:
            client-id: ${APP-CLIENT-ID}
            client-secret: ${APP-CLIENT-SECRET}
            client-name: my-client-2 email
            provider: my-client-2
            scope: user:email
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/my-client-2
```

Activated by setting the my-client-2 profile to on when running the spring boot app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=my-client-2 myApplication.jar
```

All properties can be activited by setting all profiles on:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=my-client-1,my-client-2 myApplication.jar
```